# Whats this "OFC" game that I keep seeing poker players talking about?

Tags: online, open-face-chinese

What is this "OFC" game that I keep seeing poker players talking about?

Comment: I have just seen people tweeting about playing it the last few days.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_poker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are talking about Open Face Chinese poker.

See the site below if you are interested in learning how to play:

[How to play open face chinese poker](http://www.cardplayer.com/poker-news/14256-how-to-play-open-face-chinese-poker)

A lot of the top players have started getting hooked on it. Jason Mercier was involved in a 34 hours session or something ridiculous like that.

You can also find more information about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_poker)

Answer (score 0):

"OFC" is nothing but Open Face Chinese poker, they are talking about this game.